# Photos library and storage permission for android in api level 31

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, android-manifest

I am working on React Native app.

App target sdk is 31.

I observed one thing that I am able to access all photos/documents without read permission in android.
What permission Should I add/ask for read photos and read all pdf files ?

Comment: It depends on Android version of used device.

Comment: I am using android 11 device. App doesn't ask for permission.

Comment: It is unclear how you access fotos. So there is nothing to say.

Comment: I am accessing via DocumentPicker (react-native-document-picker) and launchImageLibrary (react-native-image-picker). There should be error if I am not asking run time permission to users. But I ma able to go and select photos from gallery.

Comment: Normally one does not need any permission to pick a file. Nor does one need any permission to access/read the picked file. Unclear for what you think you need a permission. Please also give an example of an uri you get for a picked file.

Comment: I am asking DO we need ask run time "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission to select file/image from gallery ?

Comment: Again: one does not need any permission to select a file.